# Floating node error in Orcad PSpice

Tags: analog, pspice

I am new to Orcad PSpice simulation. When I tried to simulate the isolation amplifier AMC1300, I got the error like floating node and less the two connections, but I connect power symbols and gnd ref (0) properly, what do I do?

[image: attaching is the isolation amplifier schematic]

```
**** 08/05/20 17:25:46 ***** PSpice 16.6.0 (October 2012) ***** ID# 0 ********

 ** Profile: "SCHEMATIC1-sim tlv"  [ C:\CADENCE\SPB_16.6\TOOLS\CAPTURE\crystal\tlv2711 opamp-PSpiceFiles\SCHEMATIC1\sim tlv.sim ] 


 ****     CIRCUIT DESCRIPTION

*****************************

** Creating circuit file "sim tlv.cir" 
** WARNING: THIS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED FILE MAY BE OVERWRITTEN BY SUBSEQUENT SIMULATIONS

*Libraries: 
* Profile Libraries :
* Local Libraries :
* From [PSPICE NETLIST] section of C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data\cdssetup\OrCAD_PSpice/16.6.0/PSpice.ini file:
.lib "nom.lib" 

*Analysis directives: 
.TRAN  0 100ms 0 100u 
.OPTIONS ADVCONV
.PROBE64 V(alias(*)) I(alias(*)) W(alias(*)) D(alias(*)) NOISE(alias(*)) 
.INC "..\SCHEMATIC1.net" 


**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source TLV2711 OPAMP
V_V4         N3445846 0 10VDC
V_V7         0 N3445850 10VDC
V_V8         N3448327 0  
+SIN 0 5v 100hz 0 0 0
R_R5         0 N3449149  1k  
R_R6         N3448327 N3448980  1k  
R_R7         N3448980 N3448272  10K  

**** RESUMING "sim tlv.cir" ****
.END

ERROR(ORPSIM-15141): Less than 2 connections at node N3449149.

ERROR(ORPSIM-15141): Less than 2 connections at node N3448272.
```

Comment: The isolation barrier probably makes the circuit on one side of the barrier look completely isolated from the circuit on the other side. Which means you have two separate circuits on the same Spice page. Both (***all*** circuits) of these ***must*** have a galvanic connection to "0" (ground.) You can add a large resistor, if you like, to the circuit that lacks a GND reference. Or you can just tie a node to ground, so long as it doesn't otherwise cause any other troubles to do that. What you cannot do is have a floating circuit. Spice does NOT like that. Show the schematic. We fix for you. ;)

Comment: Stick a 10 MOhm resistor from pin 6 to ground.

Comment: after connecting the 10M ohm resistor from pin 6 to ground also same errors are appear,please let me know why it happens?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Add one (much bigger still) to pin 3, just in case. And perhaps now you'll need to post the Spice .SUBCKT so that we can look at it.

Comment: I can copy the amc1300 opamp from existing schematic,i am new to orcad pspice,so really i dont know the spice.subckt,please let me know the how to creat the amc1300 isolation amplifier sub circuit.

Comment: Your Spice program must be running a "subroutine" that is called a .SUBCKT in Spice. This provides everything we need to know about the simulation model, if you can find it. You need to track it down, likely. The IC datasheet shows a clear isolation barrier. But it doesn't show how it is implemented in Spice. We need to see that implementation in order to provide a specific solution. The problem is that Spice doesn't like nodes that do not have a galvanic path to GND. That's what the error you are getting is probably complaining about. So that's what needs fixing.

Comment: Do you actually have something connected to those `P5V` and `P3.3V` nodes, or is this the *entire* schematic? You had another question, recently, and these two questions tell me you don't know the basics. I recommend, heartily, that before you set out to do anything in PSpice (or any other SPICE simulator), you read and try to follow some of the tutorials that exist on the web.

Comment: In the previous question, you have copy pasted the error. If this is the same software, please copy paste the exact error message (and all surrounding text). As in the previous question, the error message will probably contain the `.subckt` mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: @Geetanjali I think you copied the error message for the circuit in the **other** question here. If so, please delete from this question.

Comment: Perhaps adding a 10M resistor on pin 3 of the OpAmp to the GND and a 10M resistor from pin 1 of the OpAmp to the GND will solve the problem.

Comment: Comparing the nodes 2 and 5 I seee a difference (at node 5 there is a small dot). Check the connection at node 2.

Answer (score 1):

These errors show that the specific nodes are floating, i.e they're just connected to one component, and aren't creating a complete circuit.

> ERROR(ORPSIM-15141): Less than 2 connections at node N3449149.
>
> ERROR(ORPSIM-15141): Less than 2 connections at node N3448272.

One particular strategy that I recommend for beginners is if you get an error like this, **try moving the components that the error is for just a little bit**. If the wires are properly connected, the wires move along with the component.

Another common mistake is accidentally putting multiple components on top of each other, which leads to a floating node error, which isn't easily seen sometimes.

You should put a little time into understanding the PSpice syntax that is seen here. It gives you the information about where the error is, and you can focus on these specific components.

TL;DR Try moving the op amp and checking the connection for pins 3 and 4

If that doesn't work, check if the op amp sub circuit is present.